# DatePicker returning Wrong Date Swift 5

Tags: swift, datepicker

**Programmatically implemented**

> set limit

```
    let calendar        = Calendar.current
    let currentDate     = Date()
    var components      = DateComponents()
    components.calendar = calendar

    components.year     = -100
    let minDate         = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: currentDate)!

    components.year     = -7
    let maxDate         = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: currentDate)!

    datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
    datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

> method call on value change

```
@objc fileprivate func datePickerChanged() {
    print(datePicker.date)
}
```

> Target

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this issue by adding the following

```
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```